# LLVM. How to access to struct fields based on their names?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I have little example code in C++:

```
struct RecordTest
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
};

void test()
{
    RecordTest rt;
    rt.value1 = 15;
    rt.value2 = 75;
}
```

and LLVM 3.4 IR for it:

```
%struct.RecordTest = type { i32, i32 }

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define void @_Z4testv() #0 {
entry:
  %rt = alloca %struct.RecordTest, align 4
  %value1 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.RecordTest* %rt, i32 0, i32 0
  store i32 15, i32* %value1, align 4
  %value2 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.RecordTest* %rt, i32 0, i32 1
  store i32 75, i32* %value2, align 4
  ret void
}
```

and a pretty easy question: How can I access to `RecordTest` fields (when I parsing .cpp), without their indexes, with only names (`value1` and `value2`)?

I know only one way (from `llc -march=cpp`) - with indexes:

```
  AllocaInst* ptr_rt = new AllocaInst(StructTy_struct_RecordTest, "rt", label_entry);
  ptr_rt->setAlignment(4);
  std::vector<Value*> ptr_value1_indices;
  ptr_value1_indices.push_back(const_int32_6);
  ptr_value1_indices.push_back(const_int32_6);
  Instruction* ptr_value1 = GetElementPtrInst::Create(ptr_rt, ptr_value1_indices, "value1", label_entry);
  StoreInst* void_9 = new StoreInst(const_int32_7, ptr_value1, false, label_entry);
  void_9->setAlignment(4);
  std::vector<Value*> ptr_value2_indices;
  ptr_value2_indices.push_back(const_int32_6);
  ptr_value2_indices.push_back(const_int32_5);
  Instruction* ptr_value2 = GetElementPtrInst::Create(ptr_rt, ptr_value2_indices, "value2", label_entry);
  StoreInst* void_10 = new StoreInst(const_int32_8, ptr_value2, false, label_entry);
  void_10->setAlignment(4);
```

So, can I translate from C++ to LLVM IR, if I don't know the indexes of the fields (`const_int32_5` and `const_int32_6` in code above) ?

UPD================================

So, we can't access to field names. And if we need it (and we do, if we parse .cpp),
 we can write something like this:

```
 // It can be some kind of singletone
static std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> mymap;

// Some function, where we first time meet RecordTest
    std::vector<std::string> fieldNames;
    fieldNames.push_back("value1");
    fieldNames.push_back("value2");
    mymap["RecordTest"] = fieldNames;

// Some function, where we need to access to RecordTest field
    std::vector<std::string> fieldNamesAgain = mymap.find("RecordTest")->second;
    std::string fieldName = "value1";
    int idxValue1 = -1;
    for (int i = 0, e = fieldNamesAgain.size(); i < e; i++) // little ugly search
    {
        if (fieldName == fieldNamesAgain[i])
        {
                // we get field index, and now we can build code
                // as in example above (llc -march=cpp)
            idxValue1 = i;  
            break;
        }
    }
```

Is this right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access the fields of the struct by name, only by index. This information is just normally not there when you compile with Clang.

There is one exception to this, and this is if you **compiled with debug information**. In that case, you'll have ample data about the type; specifically, you'll get the order of the fields, along with a metadata entry for each field which contains its name (and other useful stuff, such as its offset from the beginning of the type).

Read more about this on the [Source Level Debugging](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html) guide - and particularly, see [this section about struct encoding](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html#c-c-struct-union-types), with its very nice example.

Take a look at [DebugInfo.h](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/DebugInfo_8h.html) for classes to help on querying debug info, though I think you're going to have to do some manually digging anyway.

Comment: Thank you! So, in this case, how should I get access to this fields without debug information? I've updated question, if you have little piece of spare time, please, look at it.

Comment: @kpdev I don't get it, how will you populate `mymap` in the first place? I mean, where will you get the information about its fields from, without debug info?

Comment: From parsing .cpp file. (Or source file of other language - for example, I write a LLVM-compiler for Oberon-style lang). We can populate mymap on this step (get pairs field-index for each new struct)

Comment: @kpdev if you're using Clang, a better solution will be to compile with debug symbols. If you're not using Clang but your own front-end, then yes, the proper approach will be to encode that data in [LLVM metadata](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#metadata) during parsing (also see [this blog post](http://blog.llvm.org/2010/04/extensible-metadata-in-llvm-ir.html)) and then you could extract it from within LLVM.

Comment: Yes, I'm using my own front-end (and I write it, actually). Thank you for links, I'll have take a look at them immediately )